# How can I sync my bookmarks between browsers and computers?

Tags: sync, browser-addons, bookmarks, cross-browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sync bookmarks between Firefox, Chrome, and Safari on multiple computers?](https://superuser.com/questions/16530/how-to-sync-bookmarks-between-firefox-chrome-and-safari-on-multiple-computers)

I currently use Xmarks, but [it's going under](http://blog.xmarks.com/?p=1886) (unless it's a publicity stunt) so I'm looking for an alternative.  I need it to sync at least between Firefox and Chrome on Mac and PC, but throwing IE into the mix would be nice.  Web based access and/or backup to your own (FTP) server would be nice, but aren't essential.  I just want it to use the browser's native bookmarks without spamming me.

**Update** Dec. 2010 - It looks like Xmarks lives on thanks to LastPass. http://blog.xmarks.com/?p=2033

Comment: Damn, I'm sad to see Xmarks going under... Now I'm wondering the same thing as you.

Comment: You just ruined my day with that news :(. I've got no idea what you or I are going to do.

Answer (score 0):

[Delicious](http://www.delicious.com/) has extensions for FF, IE and Chrome. It has web access. It's also accessible over a variety of mobile devices.

Comment: From looking around the delicious site, it looks like the sync is one way - from the browser to the website.  It doesn't appear to sync the bookmarks across browsers they way Xmarks does.

Comment: Yes, it does. I.e, if you use the Delicious FF add-on, any time you add a bookmark on the web site, in a different browser or on a different computer, it appears in the Delicious bookmarks bar. You can even set sync properties (one- or two-way, clear collection etc.)