# Xmarks shuts down. Alternatives to Xmarks?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, sync, xmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sync bookmarks between Firefox, Chrome, and Safari on multiple computers?](https://superuser.com/questions/16530/how-to-sync-bookmarks-between-firefox-chrome-and-safari-on-multiple-computers)

Hi,

As you may or may not know, Xmarks (formerly Foxmarks) will shut down end of January, ceasing all activites.

Link: http://www.xmarks.com/about/shutdown

Do you know of any alternatives, free or costly that offer Cross-Browser Bookmark / Password Sync and if possible the option to handle multiple profiles (like with Xmarks)?

Thanks for helping !

Comment: Eight hour difference then. http://superuser.com/questions/193484/how-syncho-is-my-xmarks

Comment: Which earlier questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for a heads-up.
An option is to still use Xmarks extension, but setting up your own server (webdav location with basic or digest authentication).

Comment: How is that possible?  I don't see the option in the extension.

Comment: Oh, now I see... it's in the Firefox Xmarks extension, not the Safari's (as far as I can tell).

Comment: At the moment, that option is only for Firefox. Hopefully they will open it up to all supported Xmarks extensions to offer customers an option.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Firefox Sync](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10868/) and I'm happy with it.

Comment: I agree, but what about the cross browser functionality?

Comment: Sorry but there is no exact equivalent of Xmarks at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [Wikipedia's comparison of browser synchronizers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_browser_synchronizers). Most of them support bookmark syncing. Alternatively, you could consider using Google's bookmarking service. EDIT: Also, I use LastPass for cross-browser password managing. It works great.

Comment: So you say that for now I could use LastPass for passwords and then per browser? Still doesn't give us x-browser bookmarks, does it?

Comment: LastPass doesn't take care of bookmarking, no. However, Google's bookmarking service does. I understand you're trying to find an all-in-one service, but I'm not aware of another one. Sorry.