# Globally accessible bookmarks: what are my options?

Tags: browser, sync, browser-addons, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sync bookmarks between Firefox, Chrome, and Safari on multiple computers?](https://superuser.com/questions/16530/how-to-sync-bookmarks-between-firefox-chrome-and-safari-on-multiple-computers)

I have a lot of bookmarks on my work computer and personal laptop, which are not organized or synced. I'm getting really frustrated at increasingly being unable to manage the bookmarks properly.

Is there a tool or add-on that I can use to sync all my bookmarks in one location so that I have only one set of bookmarks which I can access from both my work and personal computers?

Comment: Store as files and use Dropbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[XMarks](http://www.xmarks.com/)**.  Basically, you can use the free version of this browswer addon to sync your bookmarks across multiple computers, along with a copy stored in the cloud, allowing you to browse and see your bookmarks **anywhere.**

> Install Xmarks on each computer you use, and it seamlessly integrates with your web browser and keeps your bookmarks safely backed up and in sync.
>
> Xmarks will sync across browsers too. Today we support Firefox, Chrome, Internet Explorer, and Safari (Mac OS).