# How to sync all data (bookmarks, passwords, history) between 2 browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, sync, internet-explorer

Im interested in a way to sync everything between 2 browsers, could be IE and Chrome on 1 PC. Or Chrome on my work and home computer.

Mainly im after Bookmarks, passwords, history etc.

I am aware of the duplicate [How to sync bookmarks between Firefox, Chrome, and Safari on multiple computers?](https://superuser.com/questions/16530/how-to-sync-bookmarks-between-firefox-chrome-and-safari-on-multiple-computers), but I'm after syncing more than just bookmarks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're just using Chrome, there is the option of using Chrome's builtin Sync feature. You can go to Preferences > Personal Stuff > Set Up Sync and log in with your Google account. Do this on all the computers you want to sync and everything you want synced (bookmarks, preferences, extensions, etc) will be synced.

Comment: Didn't even know about that feature, its a shame that wont work between different browsers