# Is there a way to sync Chrome bookmarks with other browsers automatically?

Tags: sync, google-chrome, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sync bookmarks between Firefox, Chrome, and Safari on multiple computers?](https://superuser.com/questions/16530/how-to-sync-bookmarks-between-firefox-chrome-and-safari-on-multiple-computers)

I normally use Google Chrome as my default browser in two different PCs. And its sync functionality automatically syncs all the bookmarks between the two browsers. Nowadays Firefox has similar auto-sync functionality. But is there any way to share Chrome bookmarks automatically across different browsers like Firefox and IE? I know it can be done manually. But I need an automated process. Maybe using some extensions/add-on?

Does any other bookmarking service provider have this functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com) will sync across browsers. It supports Firefox, Chrome, Internet Explorer, and Safari (Mac OS).