# share (offline!) bookmarks between browsers

Tags: google-chrome, browser, sync, bookmarks, tor

In light of all the NSA snooping I have begun using the TOR browser bundle (i.e. Firefox). However for some tasks I still need to use Chrome. So now I can create bookmarks in two places and it's starting to get messy.

Is there any way both applications might share a common bookmark resource? This would have to be done offline, strictly on my own computer. Because if I upload them to XMarks or whatever I might just as well announce them straight away to every snooper.

(I know, if Chrome sees my bookmarks nothing's going to stop them to grab the whole list. But I try to limit uploading my data wherever I can).

Does anyone know of a plugin or other way to share them locally?

Thanks!

Comment: I take it you don't login in Chrome (or have the sharing of Bookmarks disabled:)... I thought XMarks had the possibility of using your own server (instead of theirs). So if you set to sync to your local drive the bookmarks should be shared/synced between browsers.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I didn't know that XMarks could do that. In fact just searching now I couldn't find any recent evidence that it works (and some pages said that it "used to be possible" implying that it's not anymore). And when I installed the extension in Chrome it makes the browser crash every single time.

Comment: I noticed that there is "Firefox Sync" which I could install on my server. But I couldn't find any extensions for chrome unfortunately.

Comment: I heard it years ago, before switching to Chrome and its Bookmark sharing. I also found it [here](https://helpdesk.xmarks.com/troubleshooting/#Can+I+use+Xmarks+with+my+own+server%3F) on the helpdesk of XMarks. But maybe it doesn't work anymore after the takeover of XMarks a few years back in 2011. Either way, if the plugin doesn't work (and crashes) in Chrome it's not going to work for you :( Maybe some of the other major online bookmark-sharing plugins have the ability to sync to your own server (you could run a simple ftp-server locally in the background)

Comment: You also might want to look at [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/16530/how-to-sync-bookmarks-between-firefox-chrome-and-safari-on-multiple-computers#answer-16547). Besides [Transmute](http://www.gettransmute.com/download/) it has a link to a site with 25 other sync-apps. You just need to find the one which has offline-capabilities. (Sync between browsers or at least to you own server)

Comment: Thanks Rik. I checked the link but unfortunately I forgot to mention that I'm on a Mac (so Transmute won't work). The mashable article is from 2007 so most of the 25 deal with "sync Firefox with IE!!!", companies have folded, etc.

Comment: I'm starting to think that there's just no software around right now that would do the trick. If you or anyone here has another idea I'd be very interested. In the mean time I'll try to just add bookmarks in TOR. Thanks anyway, Rik!

Comment: Yeah, using Mac is some important piece of information ;) Maybe something like this [Bookmacster](http://www.cambridgecomputershop.co.uk/software/bookmacster-1-6-2-organize-and-manage-bookmarks-and-sync-across-browsers-shareware/) could do the job without syncing to iCloud. Don't know if that's the latest version so you should search a little to find its homepage for a more recent download. I hope for you if you disable iCloud syncing it still oerforms the cross-browser sync.

Comment: [Here](http://www.downloadsoftwareformac.com/2013/10/31/bookmacster-1-19-5-organize-and-manage-bookmarks-sync-across-browsers-demo/) is another link (maybe more recent article). Good luck.